# How can I get the contents in test.txt and display it in the p tag in HTML? I have already written some code below

Tags: python, html

file.py

```
app = Flask(__name__)

with open ('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    f_contents = f.read()
    #print(f_contents)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

test.txt
The main content of test.txt will be about 50 words

```
1) This is a test file
2) With multiple lines of data...
3) Third line
```

index.html
I want to display the contents of test.txt in HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>

    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Flask you can pass variables in the `render_template` function. My suggestion would be to pass the contents of the file to your template like so:

```
f = open("test.txt", "r")
file = f.read()

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", text=file)
```

After that, you can print out the value.
`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
    {% print(text) %}
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```